# Implement dependency check with command line params in NSIS scripts

Tags: installation, dependencies, command-line-arguments, nsis, silent

My goal is to know if you use any check or code snipp to determine if ther is some dependecy when passing NSIS command line params to copiled setup using Silent installation ( /S param ).

The NSIS sample: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_command_line_parameter_by_name

For example, If I have three params: Setup.exe /S param1="" param2="" param3=""

How to check the following secanrio:

```
${if} <Param1 is passed to Setup.exe> 
  <Param2 must ALSO be passed to Setup.exe>
${else}
  <Error message notifiing that Param1 is present, but dependent Param2 param is missing in CMD parameters>
```

Thank you!

I really hope you will share at least code snipp ... if not whole functional code.

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile test.exe
requestexecutionlevel user
silentinstall silent ;always force silent in this sample
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh

Function StripOptPrefix
Exch $0
Push $1
StrCpy $1 $0 1
${If} $1 == "="
${OrIf} $1 == ":"
    StrCpy $0 $0 "" 1
${EndIf}
Pop $1
Exch $0
FunctionEnd
!macro StripOptPrefix var
Push ${var}
call StripOptPrefix
Pop ${var}
!macroend

Section
${GetParameters} $0
${If} $0 == ""
    ;No parameters, lets run the tests
    ExecWait '"$exepath" /param1=foo'
    ExecWait '"$exepath" /param1=foo /param2=bar'
${Else}
    ${GetOptions} $0 "/param1" $1
    ${If} ${Errors}
        # /param 1 not used, do nothing?
    ${Else}
        ${GetOptions} $0 "/param2" $2
        ${If} ${Errors}
            MessageBox mb_iconstop "Missing /param2, required by /param1"
            Quit
        ${Else}
            !insertmacro StripOptPrefix $1
            !insertmacro StripOptPrefix $2
            MessageBox mb_ok "1=$1$\n2=$2"
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```